# Is it possible to get NuGet.exe running disconnected from Visual Studio?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, nuget

I've been wrestling with NuGet for a few days now and I'm turning to StackOverflow in frustration - hopefully someone here can be kind enough to point me in the right direction.

I've used NuGet several times for simple one-man pet projects, but this is the first time I've used it for something I really care about and want to have fully continuous builds, etc.  I'm trying to create a simple NAnt build script to get the source for Git, ensure the external dependencies have been brought down, compile, and run tests - vanilla CI.

I originally went down the path of trying to get solution restore working, but it just didn't work or I didn't how it worked.  Visual Studio is not on the build server and will not be installed there - that is not an option.  As an aside, I couldn't get solution restore to work just with two developers (one trying to bring down the source fresh and build cleanly).  I'm assuming it's because "allow solution restore" must be turned on everywhere (and is not by default).  I punted on that approach before I got to the bottom of it - frankly, having my package manager so tightly coupled to the IDE makes me uncomfortable and was hoping I could do it another way.  The package managers I'm used to using are simple command line tools - the CI build script invokes it on build, and developers do it on demand.  I've spent the last two hours trying to get this working with the last 30 minutes in the NuGet source code.  I feel like I'm fighting the tool and need to reboot.

Does anyone have any examples of the best to use NuGet in a multi-developer + CI scenario?  This is what I want:

1. Any and all developers can get the source and run the tests in 3 or
   less clicks (preferably 1).  If the binaries are not present locally, that will be JIT fetched.  If they are there, they will be updated if necessary, etc.  This would ideally not even require NuGet to be installed (i.e. NuGet.exe would need to be in my repo).
2. Do #1 via a CI server like Jenkins, TeamCity, etc. (preferably using the same script)
3. If its not overly fighting the tool, I would like to have all this disconnected from Visual Studio with a single packages.config file and all binaries dumped into a single Lib folder in the root of the repo.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, how I think you can achieve each your requisites:

1. You need to "Enable NuGet Package Restore" in your solution: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages
2. As @alexander-doroshenko mentioned for TeamCity you can use Nuget Installer: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/NuGet+Installer, but if you want a script to run in Jenkins, try this (works at TC too, as a command line step) for each project:

   nuget.exe install "[Project folder]/packages.config" -source "" -solutionDir "" -OutputDirectory "packages"
3. This requisite will be done by item 1 and 2.

Comment: This sounds like just want I need... and if it's from JetBrains I expect it will work well and be easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity has a build step for that, called "**NuGet Installer**", it fetch required packages from .sln file and download the locally. It does not require Visual Studio to run.

Read more about it here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/NuGet+Installer

Answer (score 0):

There are several different solutions for integrating NuGet into your build process depending on how much integration you require. In our case we wanted to use NuGet as package manager and allow developers to build their solutions even if they haven't got NuGet installed on their machine. For that to work we enabled package restore which adds the NuGet binaries to your solution folder and updates the project files. Note that NuGet doesn't always do the update of the project files correctly. In our case we found that some project files got updated but others didn't. To verify that the project was updated you will need to open the project file as XML file. To achieve this load the solution and right click the project in question and select unload project. Then right click the project again and select edit [PROJECT_NAME]. In the project file you should see

- A `RestorePackages` property in the first propertygroup. This property should have the value `true`
- An `import` statement at the very end of the project file. This import statement should point to the 'NuGet.targets file that accompanies the NuGet binary.

Below is an example of one of our project files (heavily edited)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition="'$(SolutionDir)' == '' or '$(SolutionDir)' == '*undefined*'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..</SolutionDir>
    <ProjectGuid>{8B467882-7574-41B2-B3A8-2F34DA84BE82}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyCompany.MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyCompany.MyNamespace</AssemblyName>

    <!-- Allow NuGet to restore the packages if they are missing -->
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\BaseConfiguration.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyClass.cs" />
    <!--
        .... MANY MORE FILES HERE
    -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Import the Nuget.targets file which integrates NuGet in the build process -->
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

The next step you'll need to take is to provide a solution level NuGet configuration file in which you'll indicate where the packages need to be 'installed' and what the URL of the [package repository](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) is. In our case the solution directory structure looks like:

```
(D) root
    (D) build
    (D) packages
    (D) source
        (D) .nuget
            NuGet.config
            NuGet.exe
            NuGet.targets
        (D) MyCoolProject
            MyCoolProject.csproj
        MyCoolProject.sln
    (D) templates
    NuGet.Config
```

Where `(D)` indicates a directory.

The `NuGet.config` file contains the following configuration settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="OurPackageServer" value="PACKAGE_SERVER_ADDRESS" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

This configuration file indicates that package restore is enabled, that the repository path (where the packages are placed) is the packages directory and which package sources are active.

By placing a NuGet.config file in the root directory we can use the [hierarchical configuration](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1) option with NuGet.  This allows the individual solutions to override computer specific configurations. The other benefit is that this way we don't need to have NuGet installed on the build server (because the executable and the configurations are in the repository).

With this setup developers can build the solution from Visual Studio. The build should work fine on developers machines even if they don't have NuGet installed. Note however that they won't be able to add packages to a project without having NuGet installed in visual studio.
On the build server you can simply use MsBuild to build the solution which will automatically download the packages from your package repository. Visual Studio is not required to be installed on the build machine for that (just the .NET framework of your choice).

Comment: i very much appreciate the detailed explanation.  that sounds very similar to the path i was going down.  i'm sure i could get this to work eventually, but this is waaaay more complicated than i would like it to be (multiple config files and voodoo path resolution, dependency on Visual Studio, etc.).  I would much rather having something simple - single file serving as the manifest and one thing reading that in and pulling stuff done.  I'll checkout the JetBrains stuff... thanks guys.